# What is the difference between using constructor vs state = {} to declare state in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, class-fields

I found there is two way to declare state in class component like below

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: 'John'
        }
    }

    render() {
        return  <div>{this.state.name}</div>
    }

}
```

and

```
class App extends Component {
    state = {
       name: 'John'
    }

    render() {
        return  <div>{this.state.name}</div>
    }

}
```

What is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 23):

They are roughly equivalent. The significant difference is that the initializer in the second example is executed before `constructor`.

The second approach uses [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) proposal.

It is not a part of ECMAScript standard yet so you need to set up transpiler properly to use the second approach.

**UPD** Take a look at [Babel output](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=stage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEDC5QGIEsCmIAmECiAPMAtgA4irQDeAUNDdBAC5j1kC8F1tNAdoagFzQA5ACkA9gAsugjjQC-AbhnQlwUVwYAnAK7B6ojQAoAlO041V60aQB0IUQHMDgi5p16Ngo4s6zKvyqCQMAByovBBKOhYeIQkZFScLvTauvrGpmYuVqi2Dk5JKe6e3mb04sgQ1gxMrBlm0DwE_EJiktL1Ckq-skA) to better understand how public instance fields work.

Answer (score 6):

**Use the constructor when you want to save `props` data into `state`**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: 'John'
    }
  }
}
```

**Otherwise you can directly set the `state` for hard coded data**

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: 'John'
  }
}
```

Comment: Apparently this isn't valid any more. I suceed to assign props value to the state directly in the class   state = {
    time: this.props.time,
  };

Comment: Adding a prop to the state is usually considered an anti pattern: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor. Unless you want to derive state explicitly

Answer (score 1):

When you add a method to a class, its actually being added to the function’s prototype. like so:

```
class Same{
  thing() {}
}

// Equivalent to:

function Same() {}
Same.prototype.thing = function () {}
```

*thing* is defined once and shared across all instances of the class.

If you refactor it to use Class Fields as follow:

```
class Animal {
  thing() {}
  anotherThing = () => {} // Class Field
}

// Equivalent to:

function Animal () {
  this.anotherThing = function () {}
}

Animal.prototype.thing = function () {}
```

*anotherThing* is defined on each of newly created instance rather on the prototype.

**Development Experience vs Performance**

Its a trade-off you should consider. Class Fields makes your code looks readable and clean. However, Class Fields keeps a copy of *anotherThing* in each one of your instances.

Therefore, you should carefully think if you want to use them.

Comment: "Class Fields keeps a copy of anotherThing in each one of your instances" isn't that what a constructor also does?

Comment: Hi @vikrant! Your question derives from OOP inheritance (like in Java) if I understood it correctly.

In Java, Constructors does indeed create anotherThing for each instance.

In Javascript, things behave "slightly" different. The prototype chain keeps a reference to anotherThing for each instance, which makes them lightweight & lean.

A great book series (by Kyle Simpson) sheds some light over the bare bones of Javascript fundamentals. I highly recommend you to read this section specifically: https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch5.md