# Is it correct to define the state as a variable (or property) inside a class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I found in an open source project a class like this

```
class ComponentName extends React.Component{
  state = {
    somestate here
  };

  render() {
    return <RenderedComponent value={somethings}>{some other things}</RenderedComponent>;
  }
}
```

is it correct to define `state` in this way? Shouldn't it be defined inside the class's constructor?

Comment: https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/understanding-static-in-javascript-10782149993

Comment: Please refer the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451141/what-is-the-difference-between-using-constructor-vs-state-to-declare-state. Use constructor if you want to initialize state from props

Comment: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-without-constructor

Comment: Please check solution in which i mentioned two points to remember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't always have to define a constructor for every class. So if you don't need to define a constructor it is fine to use the state this way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is perfectly correct, check this link: https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/react-alternative-class-component-syntax

You can do it both ways, in the constructor or using class field declarations.

Answer (score 1):

**yeah you can define like this it's experimental state that works similar to constructor state**.

- The only thing is you need to define arrow function instead of binding(if using experimental state).
- If you define constructor then you can bind function there

experimental state

```
state = {
name: 'hello'
```

}

state defined in constructor where you can bind function

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  name: ': hey'
}
this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

It is a new syntax of ES6. It is 100% equal define state without constructor and define state inside constructor. So feel free to write this way. To learn more about it check their documentation.