# React state (setState) with a function as a value, and class this.state with constructor vs state obj

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, constructor, state

Im really having trouble understanding the state in React. Whats the differences between,

This:

```
class Todo extends ... {
constructor (){
 super()
 this.state = { ... }
 }
}
```

And This:

```
class Todo extends ... {
 state = { ... }
}
```

And Im also confused and dumb understanding why theyre putting sometime a function inside state.

```
const [ user, setUser] = useState(() => ...)
```

I cant find any resources on differentiating those topics. I hope you can help me explained how and why is that. Ive read blogs about React but they didnt mention those things above.

Comment: `useState` is only available in function components (the ones that aren't classes). the other two are just two methods of doing the same thing for Class components. One the state is initialised with the object, the other in the constructor allows you to set the state based off the initial props passed to the component.

Comment: [What is the difference between using constructor vs state = {} to declare state in react component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45451141/what-is-the-difference-between-using-constructor-vs-state-to-declare-state) and I suspect you've seen `setUser(() => ...)` instead of `useState(() => ...)`.

Comment: No, the useState(() =>) is different. Ive seen it in yt hes using it. And I think its valid but I dont know howndoes it works.

Comment: Jacob Smith, so the state with constructor is for only passing a state to components but with a props in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Babel is adding constructor behind scenes for you, there is no need to declare it. You can just omit it and define your state like in the second example, in the end result will be exactly the same.

Comment: Thank you sir! So the, 
constructor (props){
 super(props)
 this.state = { ... } use only in the components when your passing a state on it right?

Comment: Nope, if you need to pass some date use props. Passing a state is considered bad practice, so there is really no reason to declare it inside the constructor.

Comment: Yeah yeah. Im using redux or context instead thanks for enlighting me sir!